# Scala.js - How to convert Seq to js.Iterable lazily?

Tags: scala.js

I have a `Seq[Byte]` that I need to convert to `js.Iterable[Byte]`. I have some code that does that task:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import scalajs.js.JSConverters.iterableOnceConvertible2JSRichIterableOnce

val src: Seq[Byte] = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val target: js.Iterable[Byte] = src.toJSArray
```

This code works but is likely not very efficient. Can `target` be created lazily without full array creation via `toJSArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toJSIterable`, provided by `JSConverters`, does exactly what you want:

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.JSConverters._

val src: Seq[Byte] = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val target: js.Iterable[Byte] = src.toJSIterable
```